# How to escape variable name in PHP's Heredoc?

Tags: php, string, escaping, heredoc

I have a variable `$foo` with some id in it and I want to use it in Heredoc string in PHP like this:

```
$text = <<<TEXT
  <div id="$foo_bar"></div>
TEXT;
```

Obvious problem is that PHP parses variable in Heredoc as `$foo_bar` which of course, doesn't exist. What I want is to parse `$foo` variable and "_bar" should be treated as regular text.

Is it possible to use some kind of escape character or it can't be achieved ?

P.S.: Yes, I know I can use quoted string instead of Heredoc, but I must use Heredoc (I have a ton of text and code in it with quotes, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put curly braces around the variable, just like in a quoted string.

```
$text = <<<TEXT
  <div id="{$foo}_bar"></div>
TEXT;
```

Comment: Just as an aside, note that you could also open the curlies after the `$`:  `<div id="${foo}_bar"></div>`.  It's not idiomatic PHP, but it's in keeping with the way it works in the shell and Perl.

Comment: I don't even think it's documented in the PHP manual. I guess it's just there for shell/Perl compatibility, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Barmar Sure [is documented](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Comment: @AlexandruGuzinschi It's shown in the examples, but the text of the documentation never mentions it. It only describes `{$var}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead to force using `$foo`.

```
$text = <<<TEXT
  <div id="{$foo}_bar"></div>
TEXT;
```

Curly brackets force the contents to be a variable.

Alternatively, you could attach "_bar" before the HEREDOC.

```
$foo = $foo . "_bar";
$text = <<<TEXT
  <div id="$foo"></div>
TEXT;
```

Comment: I suggest you use a new variable in the second example, rather than reusing `$foo`, e.g. `$foobar = $foo . "_bar";`

Comment: That can be good, but unless you're going to have another use for `$foo` there's no reason, just takes up more memory.